# Xcode Instruments, Time profiler - what does "View as value" stands for?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, profiling, instruments

I am profiling crucial loop in my app and I see interesting option in time profiler settings:

> "View as value"

[image]

When I select it, I see numbers with 'x' postfix instead of standard percentage values.

As an example, see attached screenshot (assembly code view):
 `and` instruction has `442x` value. This btw seems heavy for such simple assembly instruction and comparing to others in the loop.

What do those numbers mean? Are those somehow referring to the CPU cycles for given line of code?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, asked on Apple's forums for developers in their paid program. There's a Performance Tools forum in the Xcode section. An Apple engineer may be able to provide a definitive answer. My guess is the number represents the number of samples the Time Profiler instrument recorded, but I don't know Instruments' inner workings.

Comment: i have the same problem.
do you know what  x  means by now?

Comment: @sunus I don't know, but as MarkSzymczyk commented: it is highly probable that this is just an profiler samples count.